# .json is being overwriten with json.dump

Tags: python, json

I am coding a small game. I have a .json file with the names and scores of everyone that has already played the game.

First,  I import from the .json file my player's names into an array.

Second, I check if the player's name is in the array.

- if it is, there is a welcome back message
- if it is not, there is a welcome message, and the name is added to the .json file.

I receive no errors from this code,  but every-time I input a name, it overwrites the .json file.

The result is that every name is considered to be new in my python based game,  so the "welcome-message" is always displayed.

```
import json

def get_players():
    players = []
    with open ('player.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for entry in data:
            players.append(entry)
    return (players)        

noms = get_players()

nom = input("Quel est ton nom?\n")

if nom in noms:
    print('Heureux de te revoir ' , nom )
else:
    print('Bonjour', nom,', bienvenue dans mon premier programme :)\n') 
    with open("player.json", "w") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(nom, jsonFile)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    with open("player.json", "w") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(nom, jsonFile)
```

This dumps a single name into the file, and so when you load the file again `for entry in data:` will be looping over a single string giving you each character in it. You probably meant to add `nom` to `noms` and then dump `noms` here.